# Java Synchronize filewrite

Tags: java, synchronization, filewriter

I have many threads that writes to a pool of files, I want to synchronize filewriter to avoid a dirty append.

Firstly I thought about this:

```
public synchronized void write(Ing ing) {
    File file=getFile(ing);
    FileWriter writer;
    writer=new FileWriter(file,true);
    // ...
}
```

but this synchronizes all writes, and I want to synchronize only writes on THE SAME file.

Answer (score 4):

To synchronize on each file, it seems that you can synchronize on the `ing` variable, which contains a reference to the file:

```
public void write(Ing ing) {
    synchronized(ing) {
        File file = getFile(ing);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "Ing" is an entity from a Dao object, another thread could get an equal object (but not the same object!) and write to the same file. Am I right?

Comment: @Tobia If that's so, then what does `getFile()` do? If it returns the same File object, perhaps you can use that.

Comment: Yes, of course getFile() get a File object based on path String. Another time, there can be two different File object pointed to the same path...

Answer (score 1):

By default FileWrite.append() is synchronized.

View in `Writer.java`.

[image]